# visio excel link

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-access, microsoft-visio

I was wondering if is there any chance that I could connect visio with excel in dual link?
ill try to be more specific. I already linked visio with excel, I mean, I edit properties in excel and when I refresh visio they are updated. But I need to do that in the reverse. If I change shape's properties from visio, I need them to change in my excel worksheet (or MS Access database).

Can this be done?

PD: im sorry about my English, it's not my native language.

PD2:i have excel 2013 and visio 2013.
Hope u can help me

Comment: no one? :=C it can be any other database too(sql, oracle)

Answer (score 1):

Annoyingly, at present there is no mechanism that allows you to update the data via the diagram itself. You have to edit the source data.

Indeed, there still isn't a way to dynamically generate diagrams from source data either - a pet issue of mine!

Comment: On the other hand, can I create a custom data table, for example, I want to export 1 property from every shape I got, then change that property and export again, and in the database table instead of having all the shapes with their properties, in other word I want to export the current state of the diagram. I hope you understand me

Comment: Yes, you can do that certainly. Though it is rather long winded. Would it not be easier to create a simple GUI to the source data?